# Problem concerning rectangles of unit area and given semiperimeter

Tags: geometry, quadratics

Part 1 - Let the sides and semiperimeter be $x,y$ and $a$. Then we have:
$$xy = 1, x + y = a$$
Solve this system by eliminating y and thus obtaining a quadratic in $x$.

Part 2 - Solve the system of part 1 by using the identity
$$\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2 =\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2 - xy$$
Not quite sure how to get part 1 but for part 2 I was able to get the following:
$$\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{a^2}{2} -1 $$
$$x - y = ± 2\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 -1} = ± \sqrt{a^2 - 4}$$
$$x = \frac{(x+y) + (x-y)}{2}=  \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - 4}}{2}$$
$$y = \frac{(x+y) + (x-y)}{2}=  \frac{a±\sqrt{a^2 - 4}}{2}$$

Any confirmation/help with either part is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not "algebraic geometry". Tag removed.

Comment: You should really be more careful with the editing, because the question is nearly unreadable as posted. $(\frac{x=y}{2})^2 \ne \frac{a^2}{2} \ne (\frac{a}{2})^2$. Then there is a $\pm$ that's lost at one point, then reappears later.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what you're being asked to find. If it's the value of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$, it's as simple as eliminating $y$ to get $x(a-x) = 1$, putting that into the canonical quadratic form and solving it.